# C# WinForms. Enable control from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, controls

In my program, I have two forms: `public partial class Form1 : Form`,

and a log-in form: `public partial class Login : Form`. Both within the same `namespace`

Login window is opened when a Log-in button is clicked on the main window:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void LoginToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Login button event
    {
        LoginWindow = new Login();
        LoginWindow.ShowDialog();
        LogOutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

When the password is entered, I want to enable additional controls for the user, on the main screen.

groupBox2 is invisible by default, now I would like to make it visible:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Confirm click event
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == Form1.password)  //Here, no trouble accessing a string from the main screen
        {
            Form1.groupBox2.Visible = true; //********** Here is my problem **********
            Form1.LoginWindow.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Incorrect password";
            textBox1.SelectAll();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I overcome `"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Form1.groupBox2'` problem?

All my controls are already set to public.
I'm reading and reading and can't figure it out, it's driving me mad now.
I'm not expecting a ready solution, just a good explanation.

Comment: You need to pass an instance of `Form1` to `Login` so that it can access the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just raise a event on your login form like this:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
  public EventHandler OnPasswordDone; // declare a event handler

  public Login()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }

  public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
      if (textBox1.Text == Form1.password)  
      {
          // raise the event to notify main form
          OnPasswordDone(this, new EventArgs());
      }
      else
      {
          textBox1.Text = "Incorrect password";
          textBox1.SelectAll();
      }
  }
}
```

And in your main form：

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void LoginToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Login button event
    {
        LoginWindow = new Login();
        LoginWindow.OnPasswordDone += Login_PasswordDone; // regist your event here
        LoginWindow.ShowDialog();
        LogOutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void Login_PasswordDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do what you need to do here like:
        groupBox2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm, and I actually understand it too! Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score -2):

Since Form1 is not static class , so you should create object of this class then set visible to true like as

```
Form1 formobj=new Form1();
formobj.groupBox2.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Really? A new instance of `Form1`?

Comment: @Enigmativity plz suggest.i saw your comments above.. you have given same suggestion as i had suggested

Comment: No. I did not. I suggested passing a reference not creating a new one.